How to read and assert ngx-datatable values in cypress
I'm relatively new to cypress.
Our UI uses Angular components. The table data everywhere is displayed as ngx-datatable. Can someone please help me understand how to read and assert ngx-datatable values in cypress. Could not find any resource online. We are using Cypress V13.13.2
sample of code:
enter image description here
enter image description here
I want to read the table rows and columns as any regular table and assert the values.
